# Как грамотно реализовать перенаправление на новую структуру URL сайта (с названий на id)

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Сайт (PHP, Apache, htaccess) представляет собой некое подобие каталога организаций и его URL состояли из названий категорий и городов на кириллице:

[http://example.com/врачи/москва/](http://example.com/%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0/)
[http://example.com/адвокаты/екатеринбург/](http://example.com/%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B/%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3/) и так далее.

Имеется несколько десятков категорий и городов.
Теперь структура была изменена таким образом, что вместо названий категорий и городов URL состоят из их соответствующих ID, которые, как и сами названия, хранятся в таблице MYSQL:

http://example.com/7/105/
http://example.com/12/123/ и так далее.

Подскажите как лучше и грамотно реализовать (динамичное) перенаправление со старых URL на новые? То есть чтобы не прописывать для каждого старого URL новый.
Правильным вариантом кажется реализация перенаправления исключительно на PHP с передачей кода состояния HTTP 301 ... Так ли это?

Comment: оно не только кажется, но и есть правильный вариант

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать это в php где есть доступ к базе и можно найди соответствующие ID. Прямо в методе где парсится числовой урл проверять на число если не число искать по базе соответвие. modrewrite тут и не понадобится.